# How to show data of a web page in a custom layout?

Tags: android, rest, webview

I want to build a news app such that on clicking an article in a list, I will go to a new screen and the details of the article are shown there. I know that I can use webView or Custom Chrome Tab but I want it to look different than it looks on the website(like in the image below).

I am getting the news data from NewsApi.org.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wuj0.png)